# Ominauth-evernote, OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, omniauth, evernote

Am using omniauth-evernote gem

omniauth.rb

```
provider :evernote, EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_KEY, EVERNOTE_CONSUMER_SECRET ,:client_options => { :site => 'https://www.evernote.com' }
```

Am not able to understand why this is happening
If i try sandbox 'https://sandbox.evernote.com' everything is working perfectly right. But i need for prodution.

In server log, this is the error

```
OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
  omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:29:in `request_phase'
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you activate your API Key on the production?  If not, you can do that here: http://dev.evernote.com/support/

If you have already done that and still have the issue, you can contact Evernote developer support.
http://dev.evernote.com/support/faq.php#getsupport